# PHP bound variables, Invalid parameter number error or PDO Update Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I built a update statement in PHP using PDO, however I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I have counted and re-counted (25) and spent a while making sure my syntax is correct and I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE :tablename
        SET entryName = :entryname,
        entryAdd1 = : add1,
        entryAdd2 = :add2,
        entryCity = :city,
        entryCounty = :county,
        entryCountry = :country,
        entryPC = :postcode,
        entryPhone = :phone,
        entryEmail = :email,
        entryURL = :entryurl,
        entryDesc = :entryDesc,
        entryImg = :entryimg,
        entryStar  = :star,
        entryCuststar = :custstar,
        chains = :chains,
        cafe = :cafe,
        fishandchips = :fishandchips,
        indian = :indian,
        itallian = :italian,
        pizzeria = :pizzeria,
        tapas = :tapas,
        tearooms = :tearooms
        WHERE :colname = :entryid";

        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bindParam(":tablename", $tablename, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $statement->bindParam(":entryname", $entryname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":add1", $add1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":add2", $add2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":city", $entrytown, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":county", $entrycounty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":country", $entrycountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":postcode", $entrypostcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":phone", $entryphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":email", $entryemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":entryurl", $entryurl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":entryDesc", $entrydesc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":entryimg", $entryicon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":star", $star, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":custstar", $custstar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":chains", $chains, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":cafe", $cafe, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":fishandchips", $fishchips, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":indian", $indian, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":italian", $italian, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":pizzeria", $pizzeria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":tapas", $tapas, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(":tearooms", $tearooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $statement->bindParam(":colname", $colname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(":entryid", $entryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $count = $statement->execute();
```

I state the $conn variable further up, it's just a practice directory I was making. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: you can't parameterize table/column names the resultant query would be `UPDATE 'table_name' ...` quotes included!

Comment: and i do not know, is it matter, but you have an extra space here `entryAdd1 = : add1,`

Comment: @andrew if I hard-code the table name and column name I end up with the same error, I am not disputing you are right, just that it appears to make no difference to this error. But thank you for explaining that, I had just done something similar before.

Comment: I think @lolka_bolka has spotted why the number of params dont match

Comment: When you hardcoded the table name and column name, did you make sure to remove those two bindParam statements?

Answer (score 1):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.
You'd have to replace these with the actual names, offcourse you can filter out unwanted data if you wanted to, but not by using the prepared statements.

Won't work:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM ?  WHERE calories < ?');
```

THIS WORKS!

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < ?');
```

Comment: Just for clarification: that relates to the `UPDATE :tablename` and the `WHERE :colname` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize table/column names. Try this if you need them to be dynamic:

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . $tablename . "
    SET entryName   = :entryname,
    entryAdd1       = :add1,
    entryAdd2       = :add2,
    entryCity       = :city,
    entryCounty     = :county,
    entryCountry    = :country,
    entryPC         = :postcode,
    entryPhone      = :phone,
    entryEmail      = :email,
    entryURL        = :entryurl,
    entryDesc       = :entryDesc,
    entryImg        = :entryimg,
    entryStar       = :star,
    entryCuststar   = :custstar,
    chains          = :chains,
    cafe            = :cafe,
    fishandchips    = :fishandchips,
    indian          = :indian,
    itallian        = :italian,
    pizzeria        = :pizzeria,
    tapas           = :tapas,
    tearooms        = :tearooms
    WHERE " . $colname . " = :entryid";

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $statement->bindParam(":entryname", $entryname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":add1", $add1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":add2", $add2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":city", $entrytown, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":county", $entrycounty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":country", $entrycountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":postcode", $entrypostcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":phone", $entryphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":email", $entryemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":entryurl", $entryurl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":entryDesc", $entrydesc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":entryimg", $entryicon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":star", $star, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":custstar", $custstar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(":chains", $chains, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":cafe", $cafe, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":fishandchips", $fishchips, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":indian", $indian, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":italian", $italian, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":pizzeria", $pizzeria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":tapas", $tapas, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(":tearooms", $tearooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $statement->bindParam(":entryid", $entryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $count = $statement->execute();
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: be careful of where `$tablename` is coming from, you don't want to introduce injection vulnerabilities